# COA - tool blender animation

Tags: animation, mesh, add-on

have question regarding COA tool for animating sprites in blender,is it possible to animate mesh deformations,I see options for selecting meshes and moving them,but none for animation,right now I am cheating using bones structure in Blender,but really hope to achieve effect similar to the one which can be created with DragonBones and Spine2d tool.So is there a way to animate deformation without bones currently with this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Blender refers to morphs/deformations as "shape keys".  They can be found in your mesh's properties panel, and looks like this (from the manual):

[image: Blender manual image of shape keys modifier]

You can animate these shapes by messing with their value (the "Value" slider) and then right-clicking it and Adding a key.  You can also setup drivers for the shape blend value as well.

Please remember that shape deformations don't export easily, as most file formats don't support it.